# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems : WebDriver/ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type error while executing selenium tests

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my code:

```
package seleniumTutorials;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class BasicsSelenium {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean status;
    status=true;
    boolean newstatus = false;

    System.out.println("My Old status was "+status);
    System.out.println("My new status was "+newstatus);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Samraj\\MavenAutomation\\Jar Files\\Selenium Java\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("dev.findmyfare.io");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
 }
 }
```

Below is the error message which am getting after declaring webdriver concept:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type   ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    at seleniumTutorials.BasicsSelenium.main(BasicsSelenium.java:13)
```

Note: I can able to execute simple java program.

[Screenshot of my Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0bAQ.jpg)

Comment: You seem to be missing some jars for the Selenium project. Have you added Selenium in the build path and added the jars?

Comment: Also `driver.get("dev.findmyfare.io")` will throw an error. Please use `http` or `https` before the url

Comment: I had added Junit jar which was missing and still am facing the same issue. I had changed the directing url as well to https://dev.findmyfare.io.

Comment: I had this problem with Eclipse but with NetBeans I didn't have any problems          I think this can help you           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361521/opening-chrome-in-selenium-issue/59361910#59361910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type
```

...implies that *WebDriver* and *ChromeDriver* wasn't resolved at **compiletime**.

As per the snapshot you have shared your main issue is the presence of **multiple** similar binaries within your project space as follows :

- You have included **selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0** as a dependency.
- Additionally you have included the *Java Client JARs* from **selenium-java-3.11.0** as a dependency.

As a result it is pretty much possible that you have **resolved** the *WebDriver* and *ChromeDriver* from one JAR resource (i.e. either *selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0* or *selenium-java-3.11.0* JARs) but **compiletime** the Classes are trying to get resolved from the other JAR. Hence you see **java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems**

### Solution

- Either keep only  **selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0** JAR as an external JAR.
- Or keep only  **selenium-java-3.11.0** JARs as an external JARs.
- Remove all the other *Selenium Java Client JARs*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code. I created a simple Selenium project and added this code and I was able to run this code without any problem.

Please see that in your External Jars you need to have the following jar files

- client-combined-3.11.0.jar
- client-combined-3.11.0-sources.jar
- byte-buddy-1.7.9.jar
- commons-codec-1.10.jar
- commons-exec-1.3.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- gson-2.8.2.jar
- guava-23.6-jre.jar
- httpclient-4.5.3.jar
- httpcore-4.4.6.jar
- okio-1.13.0.jar
- okhttp-3.9.1.jar

Edit 1 : Also remove `ChromeDriver` from the `Referenced Libraries`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I checked in my project, i do have all the jars added which you had listed above.

Comment: Use the debug feature.

Comment: I used debug feature and still  i could not figure out the issue... Can you explain me how i can get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while working with IntelliJ IDEA, and the solution was to update my Gradle file "build.gradle" to include

```
dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()}
```

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse, while adding the jar files , we have two options first one is modulePath and second one is classPath,
so you need to add all the required jar files in classPath not in ModulePath
it works for me

Answer (score 0):

In older Eclips we didn't had option to add jars under class path or Module path.

Now we have an options, so if you add all valid jars in module path and still if you are getting error then it is because of adding jars in Module path.

Remove the jars and add under Classpath

Attached screenshot for reference

[Screenshot to fix ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYukd.png)