# opening chrome in selenium issue

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently taking my first automated test class and the instructor has us creating a program in Eclipse after loading Selenium and create a step in the program to look at an executable to bring up chrome then designate a website to check.  It looks like i am stuck in a loop?

Here is the program:
[java program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7nLo.png)

Here is the result:
[program result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue2LB.png)

any and all help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is what you want**

This code is to open the default browser and go to a specific link
You can specify the path of any browser you want from the path in the code

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

public class openBrowser {

    public openBrowser() {
        try {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported() && Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.google.com"));
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
        public static void main(String[]args) {
            new openBrowser();
        }
}
```

**For your code you can follow the following steps**

- Download ChromeDriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
- Extract the zip file and follow the path ( because it is easy ) `C:\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe`
- include the ChromeDriver location in your PATH environment variable
- Download the required Libraries from the following [junit](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjunitjar.htm) [openqa](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.4.0/source-code)
- Add the Libraries to your project ( Build Path )
- then this is your code

  ```
  import java.util.logging.Level;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;
  import org.openqa.selenium.*;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;
  import org.junit.Test;

  public class WebDriverDemo {
      @Test
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
      WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
      searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
      searchBox.submit();
          try {
              Thread.sleep(10000);

          } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(WebDriverDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```

During the implementation of the code in the eclipse, many problems occurred, so I advise you to implement the project on NetBeans
I use Java 8 and Windows 8.1

Comment: Thank you for your input Wassim.  Your suggestion worked perfectly. Just out of curiosity, If i wanted to try to use the code that was suggested from the instructor , how or what changes would have to be made to that code if possible?  Please let me know at your earliest convenience.  Thank you again.

Comment: Very sorry for the late reply