# Selenium Java setup eclipse

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to java in selenium i am setting up the below code however eclipse is unable to recognize the webdriver and chromedriver below are the snap can someone please help me on this. I have also downloaded the JARS and kept it on the the libraries

[image]

Comment: Looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114884/8370915) is related to your question. Please, check it. If it doesn't help you, update your question with attempts to continue investigation.

Comment: This video could help you. [Selenium java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJZop3GZWQU&lc=Ugw4fM2arcxSvYEieHx4AaABAg.9S8bG9W9G3c9SLFsYZMChk)

Answer (score 0):

you write that you have jar in the libraries.
Do you mean a libraries on a filesystem or a libraries in a project?
If not - then the JAR needs to be inserted into the Project (see picture)[Project / Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik6PV.png)