# Getting "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem" error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {                            
        
    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables       
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\User\\chromedriver.exe");                  
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();                  
            
    String baseUrl = "";                    
    driver.get(baseUrl);                    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Get the WebElement corresponding to the Email Address(TextField)     
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("fname"));                          

    // Get the WebElement corresponding to the Password Field       
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));    
    
    WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Log in')]"));

    email.sendKeys("hansi");                    
    password.sendKeys("Hansi@123"); 
    btnLogin.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Text Field Set");                   
     
    Assert.assertEquals( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Messages')]")).getText(), "Messages");     
            
}
```

}

This is the error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

```
at newpackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:16)
```

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Added the code can you look into that

Comment: Define `WebDriver driver` outside of the main method, and then inside main call it like this `driver = new ChromeDriver();`

Comment: Have a look at [tour] and [mcve] and edit it accordingly to receive the correct answers

Comment: Can you send me the code after rebuild

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you can you send me the link

Comment: Can you try this solution - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111517/java-lang-error-unresolved-compilation-problems-webdriver-chromedriver-cannot)

Comment: I tried that but still the same